# Problem with Authorization and variations in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Hello i have a website in Sharepoint that is using variations. I have for sites with variation: ES, CA, EU, EN.  I use authorization with roles and i put restrictions in the location tag in web.config. This is not working. Everybody can enter es/admin.

```
<location path="es/admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="administrators" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But, if I use one site that is not a variation, for example, like this:

```
<location path="prueba">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="administrators" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

it works, there is a redirection.

If this is not possible, please give alternatives, i use a custom membership provider and role provider, so how can i restrict this site in a variation to only a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because variations aren't actual locations and so the web.config option won't work - they are a little url trick which defines what is read from the database.

Comment: but it works for a site called "prueba" which is not a variation. Everything is supposed to be in database, even the site "prueba"

Comment: correct, variations are NOT the same as sites. variations aren't actual locations and don't work. sites are locations and thus will work.

Comment: Any alternatives? I have the roles in my database and i implement a custom membership provider.